# Django ORM & Unit of Work

Tags: python, django, orm, django-models, django-orm

Is there any easy way / library / external app to introduce Unit of Work concept to Django ORM? What approaches or techniques do you use to solve the problem of importing the same row twice in a complicated model setup without loosing all the modularity?

**EDIT**

*Example*

Consider the following *examplatory* situation - there is a model `Location` which has a relationship with itself called route through an additional model `Route`. Now let's say each `Route` has attributes called: `entry_fare` (the amount of money you need to pay to enter the route) and `exit_fare` (the amount of money you need to pay to exit the route on its other end). Now let's say you want to implement an action of augmenting the `entry_fares` and augmenting `exit_fares`. You also want to be able calculate the total sum of fares for a given city. You may want to perform a series of such actions inside a single transaction. Reads (comuting the sum) are much more frequent than writes (augmenting the fares).

In a naive implementation you would need to load a fresh set of models each time you want to calculate the sum - to ensure there is no stale data. Also augmenting would operate on a new set of models each time and would save instances immediately after the fare is augmented to ensure that further fetches from the database include the new fare values.

Remember, this is meant to serve as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but a few years ago David Cramer wrote a library called [Django-identitymapper](http://justcramer.com/2008/12/02/singletons-in-django/) - could that fit the bill?

Comment: Interesting, will be looking into that. What about having multiple threads - will it keep a single instance of a model for each one of those?

Answer (score 1):

You can execute [raw SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/), or [manage the transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/). [Managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/managers/) also make it very easy to implement custom functionality and precise control over your models. You might want to consider using [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/features.html) instead, it has built-in support for this.

Sounds like you're mostly interesting in caching models, [django-cache-machine](http://jbalogh.me/projects/cache-machine/) handles caching/invalidation using memcached.

Comment: raw SQL - in most cases totally violates modularity. Managed transactions - I don't see any direct connection to the topic. Managers - I think you'd have to be more specific about what kind of custom managers you'd like to propose. SQLAlchemy - yea, but I specifically asked about Django ORM. Besides, getting rid of Django ORM in Django actually breaks most of the apps out there.

Comment: My understanding of a 'Unit of Work' being a managed set of operations, thus making management of the transactions essential to the implementation of the pattern. Perhaps you could define your concept of Unit of Work in your question? If nothing else it will help people that might read your question in the future.

Comment: I meant this: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html. Don't get me wrong - it has a lot to do with transactions, but these are not transactions that are the difficult part here.

Comment: What is the hard part? Can edit your example to be a bit more explicit? A precise example outlining models involved, operations on them, how you want the transaction(s) to be managed, default behavior vs. expected? Django already gives you pretty easy control over transactions, tracks state of objects, etc. I'm not understanding what it doesn't do, that you want.

Comment: Well, there is no easy way to introduce caching of models in this setup, right? What UoW does is keep every model just once, even if there are multiple places in the code that attempt to load it. In Django ORM, you'll get multiple instances representing the same row in the database. If you update one of them, the other become stale. If you do not introduce caching you generate big overhead as you are reading the same data over and over again killing the db. In UoW you'd read every row (for example route) just once. Then save it just once.

Comment: Django will already do that for you. It doesn't fetch instances over and over again. If you did Route.objects.all(), you can iterate over all the instances making changes to them, etc. The only issues I really see are: Django doesn't support batch inserts, and it doesn't support row-level locking, although both can be worked around.

Comment: Each time you call `Route.objects.all()` you get another QuerySet that will produce a list of fresh models. That said QuerySet is iterable but that's a different story. Also if you do `location.input_routes.all()` and then `location2.output_routes.all()` and there is a route from `location` to `location2`, there won't be any model instance shared between the two returned lists. If you ask exactly the same QuerySet for results twice - then you have caching, but that's *very* limited.

Comment: A lot of this can be solved by refactoring I'd wager. Without any concrete example it's hard to say "Do that instead", but this isn't an issue I've ever faced, honestly. If you know you'll need a batch of routes which match a batch of locations, you can very simply just do `Route.objects.filter(location__in=locations)` and fetch them all up front. It sounds like you are mostly interested in caching, I think django-cache-machine appropriate.

Comment: I'll look into django-cache-machine, thank you. Well, I can't really give any more details as this is a pretty general problem, and I face it each time I do something a little bit more advanced and write-intensive. In Hibernate or in SQLAlchemy it's nonexistant as UoW is in place. There are other problems this causes, but it's a pretty popular solution. In Django I can write one big batch update blob and it will work, but it's something I try to avoid as much as possible. I've developed some ways to do that, just curious what others use.

Comment: I would agree lack of batch insert support is a pain. You could also consider using `@transaction.commit_on_success()`, on your view. While not as efficient as a true batch insert, it can still be quite a lot faster for bulk updates. There is also `Queryset.update`, which can be useful for simple batch updates. One other thing of note, in the dev version of Django they've added `select_for_update`, which will perform row-level locking for you.